# 2nd hard drive shows up in BIOS but not recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hard-drive

system is a Dell Precision 7740

Ubuntu 20.04, up-to-date

Hard drive is in "slot 4" according to the [service manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/precision-17-7740-laptop/precision_7740_service%20manual/removing-the-m.2-solid-state-drive%e2%80%94ssd-module?guid=guid-4b6f7f96-46a2-4752-8d15-d7f7357154f6&lang=en-us)

In the list of SSD devices in BIOS, I see the disk listed as NVME #0 (the disk I'm booting off of shows up as #1)

However, it doesn't seem to be recognized at all by Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: Micron 2200S NVMe 256GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   2685MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
 3      2685MB  4833MB  2147MB  zfs
 4      4833MB  256GB   251GB   zfs
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 55.37 MiB, 58052608 bytes, 113384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 255.58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 162.66 MiB, 170545152 bytes, 333096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 162.89 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 55.33 MiB, 58007552 bytes, 113296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 217.92 MiB, 228478976 bytes, 446248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 43.16 MiB, 45248512 bytes, 88376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 30.95 MiB, 32432128 bytes, 63344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: Micron 2200S NVMe 256GB                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 29DA9A63-5758-4645-9F36-411AD08F7AB0

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   5244927   4194304    2G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p3 5244928   9439231   4194304    2G Solaris boot
/dev/nvme0n1p4 9439232 500118158 490678927  234G Solaris root


Disk /dev/loop8: 50.69 MiB, 53133312 bytes, 103776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 240.79 MiB, 252465152 bytes, 493096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 30.96 MiB, 32440320 bytes, 63360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: I switched to slot #3 and now Ubuntu recognizes it. I don't know what that tells me regarding this problem

Comment: Dell UEFI and SSD's often need firmware update. Check your versions.